# Optimization on data retrieval

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to retrieve each class attendance as follows, but I wonder there is a better way to handle it, instead of calling three times `GetAttendanceLastMonth` method for each class, is there a way to call only once and get all these information.

```
List<Attendance> chemistry = GetAttendanceLastMonth(schoolId, chemistryId);
List<Attendance> math = GetAttendanceLastMonth(schoolId, mathId);
List<Attendance> music = GetAttendanceLastMonth(schoolId, musicId);
//Plotting them on the chart based on date (x axis) and attendance number(yaxis) values

public List<Attendance> GetAttendanceLastMonth(string schoolId, string classId)
{
   try
   {
       var attendanceNumber = Repository.Get(x => x.SchoolId.Equals(schoolId)).Where(x => x.ClassId.Equals(classId) && 
       (DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(x.AttendanceDate.Date)).TotalDays >= 0 && 
       (int)(DateTime.Now.Date - x.AttendanceDate.Date).TotalDays <= 30).ToList();

       attendanceNumber.Sort((x, y) => x.AttendanceDate.CompareTo(y.AttendanceDate));
       return attendanceNumber ;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you group to return a dictionary<string, list<attendance>>?

Comment: Does the current repository call result in three queries against the database? You can consolidate your database query to a single call, but then you'd still have to split them into different collections in memory. Is it a huge data set that's coming back? Consolidating at this point might be a premature optimization.

Comment: @hotspring Exception handling is a Pet Peeve of mine. And the code you showed, does the deadly sin of Exception handling - swallowing Fatal Exceptions. Keeping it that way will get you no end of unrepdictable, undebugable followup errors so you should propably go and fix that mid-term. Here are two articles on the mater that I do link often: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @hotspring: I did not mean mid-term as in school. But as in "not quite now, but also not quite the last thing you do with that code". Especially if this is productive code, you can not swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a dictionary, the key is the `ClassId` and the value is a `List<Attendance>` and you can use `Contains` to check multiple `ClassId`s:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<Attendance>> GetAttendanceLastMonth(string schoolId, params string[] classIds)
{
    DateTime monthStart = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-DateTime.Today.Day);
    DateTime nextMonthStart = monthStart.AddMonths(1);

    Dictionary<string, List<Attendance>> attendancesDictionary = Repository
        .Get(x => x.SchoolId == schoolId)
        .Where(x => classIds.Contains(x.ClassId))
        .Where(x => x.AttendanceDate.Date >= monthStart && x.AttendanceDate.Date < nextMonthStart)
        .GroupBy(x => x.ClassId)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.OrderBy(x => x.AttendanceDate).ToList());
    return attendancesDictionary;
}
```

You can access each list via key:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Attendance>> attendancesDictionary =
   GetAttendanceLastMonth(schoolId, chemistryId, mathId, musicId);

// for example the music-list:
List<Attendance> music = attendancesDictionary[musicId];
```

Comment: I believe it would be nice to check dictionary `containsKey` to avoid the crash.